# filling excel column automatically where another column is not null

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to fill an excel column with a specific value where another column in the same sheet is not null(I've used '-' for all the empty cells). Can I automate this?

For example, in the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGczR.png), where ever I have a value, I want to insert 'Hi' (Only at the places with a value) and omit where there is blank space represented by '-'. Also, it should not edit the values in B column if there is anything already present in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use if function to do this task. Suppose you have data to test in Cell A1 then you can enter Formula in cell B1 as =if(A1<>"-","Hi","") this means if Data in cell A1 is not - then enter Hi in cell B1 else keep B1 empty. See Screenshot attached.

[image]

Comment: Note the counter does not add a number until after a blank cell.

Comment: This works absolutely fine, but can I automate this for the whole column?

Comment: Also, it replaces previously filled rows of that column with blanks if the condition doesn't satisfy. Can we avoid that? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following: suppose column A is full of values and you want to fill column B with "-". First, write the value "-" in the cell "C1", then select column B and write in B1 =$C$1 and then press Ctrl+Enter Key that's it

[image]

Comment: Im sorry I think I was not clear enough in my question. I have updated it, Please view my question again.

Answer (score 0):

`=IFERROR(IF(B1="","-",COUNTBLANK(INDIRECT("B1:B"&ROW()-1))+1),1)`

[image]

Or avoiding `INDIRECT`:
`=IFERROR(IF(B1="","-",SUM(IF(INDEX(B:B,SEQUENCE(ROW()-1))="",1))+1),1)`

Comment: I need to modify this according to my needs, can you please explain how this formula works? I'm not able to figure out on my own. Thanks

Comment: It checks if the value in column B is empty otherwise returns the array of all cells before the current row of column B and sums the number of cells in that range that are blank (+1). Both count the same, but INDIRECT is volatile and will recalculate (each cell containing that function) on any cell change in the workbook and will slow things down.

Comment: `INDEX(B:B, SEQUENCE (ROW()-1))` would return the following in for instance cell `A3`: `INDEX(B:B,{1,2}))` 
(SEQUENCE 3-1 = 2) being cells `B1` and `B2`.